# How to extract all hashtags from string by using regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I need a regex pattern which extracts all hastags from a tweets in a table.
My data like is

```
select regexp_substr('My twwet #HashTag1 and this is the #SecondHashtag    sample','#\S+')
from dual
```

it only brings #HashTag1 not #SecondHashtag

I need a output like #HashTag1  #SecondHashtag

Thanks

Comment: You say you need the output in that format, but in most cases you should look for output in separate rows (like GurV shows in his second approach).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace` to remove all that doesn't match your pattern.

```
with t (col) as (
  select 'My twwet #HashTag1 and this is the #SecondHashtag    sample, #onemorehashtag'
  from dual
)
select 
  regexp_replace(col, '(#\S+\s?)|.', '\1')
from t;
```

Produces;

```
#HashTag1 #SecondHashtag #onemorehashtag
```

`regexp_substr` will return one match. What you can do is turn your string into a table using `connect by`:

```
with t (col) as (
  select 'My twwet #HashTag1 and this is the #SecondHashtag    sample, #onemorehashtag'
  from dual
)
select 
  regexp_substr(col, '#\S+', 1, level)
from t
connect by regexp_substr(col, '#\S+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Returns:

```
#HashTag1
#SecondHashtag
#onemorehashtag
```

#### EDIT:

\S matches any non space character. It would be better to use \w which matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _.

As commented by @mathguy and from [this](https://www.hashtags.org/featured/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/) site:
a hashtag starts with an alphabet, then alphanumeric characters or underscores are allowed.

So, pattern `#[[:alpha:]]\w*` will work better.

```
with t (col) as (
  select 'My twwet #HashTag1, this is the #SecondHashtag. #onemorehashtag'
  from dual
)
select 
  regexp_substr(col, '#[[:alpha:]]\w*', 1, level)
from t
connect by regexp_substr(col, '#[[:alpha:]]\w*', 1, level) is not null;
```

Produces:

```
#HashTag1
#SecondHashtag
#onemorehashtag
```

Comment: This looks good, and the second solution is probably the one that makes more sense in most situations. You also need to handle punctuation though, and non-alphanumeric characters more generally; you may have something like `'My hashtag is #MyHashtag, yours is #YourHashtag, etc.'` - here the hashtags should not pick up the comma as part of the hashtag.

Comment: I just checked Twitter hashtags: they must begin with a letter and must contain only letters, digits and the underscore. So something like `'#[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*` should work. (Not sure if there is also a minimum length; that can be easily accommodated.)

Comment: @mathguy - Updated the answer. Thanks for the comment.